# How do you convert a base64 image to a base64Binary with Scala

Tags: scala

I'm developing a gateway in Scala with Finagle libraries. This gateway sits between mobile apps and my client's existing web services.

The web service description (hosted on .Net) for a file upload method specifies the expected file content as follows:

```
  <FileContents>base64Binary</FileContents>
```

On the mobile side, the apps are uploading content to the gateway using PhoneGap's FileTransfer object. This means that the image gets to the gateway as a base64-encoded string.

How do I convert from the base64-encoded string to a base64Binary using Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer [through a related question I had.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9739473/828757)

I suppose this question can be safely deleted, but may help others get to the right answer:

```
scala> import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

scala> <FileContents>{Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes)}</FileContents>
res1: scala.xml.Elem = <FileContents>AQIDBAUGBwgJCg==</FileContents>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the external dependency is an issue you could use [this simple encoder/decoder](http://github.com/marklister/base64).